# how to debug RN WebView when source is localhost site in iphone?

Tags: ios, react-native, webview, localhost

I create a RN app which only have a webview with localhost resource(e.g. source={{uri: 'http://10.123.23.200:3000'}}) in my PC, now I debug the app in my iphone with expo,it display nothing except a error like

> (Encountered an error loading pae
>   {"domain":"NSURLErrorDomain","description":"Could not connect to the
>   server","code":-1004})

. I try it with `localhost:3000` and `10.0.2.2:3000`,but it does not work. what should I do?

Comment: try opening http://10.123.23.200:3000 in your mobile phone browser. Let me know what happens

Comment: the PC and iphone are in the same inner network, it works well when i open the page(10.123.23.200:3000) directly in safari. when I debug the app through the PC hotspot, it just shows white blank without any error. It can trigger onLoadEnd event but not onError event.

Comment: try finding your computer's IP address using either ( ifconfig | grep inet ) in mac terminal or ( ipconfig/ALL ) in windows cmd. One of these should work as the WebView uri: exhttp://194.178.1.2:4242/my-local-endpoint